# Django add a custom link in admin list with an ID url link

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have my django admin models list page and i would to add a custom column for every single items in ilst wit a custom a href with item.id as parameter:

```
<a href="http://test/<item.id>">Go to example page </a>
```

Here my actual page:

[image]

How can i add my custom liink on every list item and get an item field value?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :)

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['custom_coulmn']

    def custom_coulmn(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="http://test/{obj.id}">Go to example page </a>')
```

It will add a column with `custom_coulmn` name.

Comment: Super! but i get <a href="http://test/45">Go to example page </a> not the html representation in my admin list